# Is there a simple way to calculate the sum of the duration for each hour in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe simmilar to this one:

| user | start_date | end_date | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-21 07:23:58 | 2022-05-21 14:23:48 | Sleep |
| 2 | 2022-05-21 12:59:16 | 2022-05-21 14:59:16 | Eat |
| 1 | 2022-05-21 18:59:16 | 2022-05-21 21:20:16 | Work |
| 3 | 2022-05-21 18:50:00 | 2022-05-21 21:20:16 | Work |

I want to have a dataframe in which the columns will be certain activities and the rows would contain the sum of the duration of each of these activities for all users in that hour. Sorry,  I find it hard to even put my thoughts into words. The expected result should be simillar to this one:

| hour | sleep[s] | eat[s] | work[s] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 07 | 2162 | 0 | 0 |
| 08 | 3600 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 18 | 0 | 0 | 644 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The dataframe has more than 10 milion rows so I'm looking for something fast. I was trying to do something with *crosstab* to get expected columns and *resample* to get the rows, but I'm not even close to find a soluction. I would be really grateful for any ideas of how to do that. This is my first question, so I apologize in advance for all mistakes :)

Comment: where did you get 2162 from? can you explain your output

Comment: from 07:23:58 to 8:00:00 there is 36 minutes and 2 seconds so 36*60+2=2162[s]. For each hour  I'm trying to calculate the sum of the duration of each activity in that hour. For that specific cell I'm calculating the sum (in seconds) of sleeping time for each user in that hour (from 7 to 8).

Comment: This is not an easy one.Seems you do not have enough points to open a bounty on it.

Comment: My thoughts are to create more columns for each the start and end like two for hour, and two for (minute and second). Then you would use some subtraction. But I can't think of a fast way to do this. Maybe after you figure out an algorithm, sql could be faster.

Comment: @Nohman I thought about it too, but in the end the accuracy is to be for a selected period of time, e.g. 10 seconds. Later, unfortunately, the data will be a few petabytes and so far I can't use sql for all that data. For now, I'm trying to come up with a good and fast solution on a fraction of them.

Comment: Well I suggest you start with some method, edit your answer with what method you are doing to achieve this. Maybe people would be able to help out more like that.

Comment: Your problem is really interesting. Is it reasonable to consider each activity (row) does not never exceed 24 hours?

Comment: In your question you said: " sum of the duration of each of these activities for all users in that hour"
Then in your comment: "For that specific cell I'm calculating the sum (in seconds) of sleeping time for each user in that hour (from 7 to 8)"
I want to be sure, for EACH unique user for EACH day you'll have a 24 rows (24hours) dataframe right? Or you want ALL the users for the same day, the same hour in the same 24 rows dataframe? Because if it the latter, it won't be possible I think. Interesting case anyway :)

Comment: @Corralien I think it's enough if we assume that all the dates are from the same day. This will probably be the easiest way.

Comment: @Drakax Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly enough. I want  "ALL the users for the same day, the same hour in the same 24 rows dataframe" :)

Comment: So, what is the length (rows / index axis) of the expected output: "USERS x DAYS x HOURS" or "DAYS x HOURS" or "USERS x HOURS" or "HOURS"?

Comment: @Corralien Just "HOURS" would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you the activities start time can span more than one day and you actually want the summary for each day. If not, the answer could be adapted by using `datetime.hour` instead of binning the start time.

The answer:

1. Calculate the duration at the top of the hour intervals
2. Expand the rows of 1-hour intervals
3. pivot the dataframe by activity

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


data={'users':[1,2,1,3],
      'start':['2022-05-21 07:23:58', '2022-05-21 12:59:16', '2022-05-21 18:59:16', '2022-05-21 18:50:00'],
     'end':[ '2022-05-21 14:23:48', '2022-05-21 14:59:16', '2022-05-21 21:20:16', '2022-05-21 21:20:16'],
'activity':[ 'Sleep', 'Eat', 'Work', 'Work']
}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

#concert to datetime
df.start=pd.to_datetime(df.start)
df.end=pd.to_datetime(df.end)

#Here is where the answer starts

# function to expand the duration in a list of one hour intervals
def genhourlist(e):
    start = e.start
    end = e.end
    nexthour = datetime(start.year,start.month,start.day,start.hour) + timedelta(hours=1)
    lst=[]
    
    while end > nexthour:
        inter = (nexthour - start)/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
        lst.append((datetime(start.year,start.month,start.day,start.hour),inter))
        
        start=nexthour
        nexthour=nexthour+timedelta(hours=1)
    
    inter = (end - start)/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
    lst.append((datetime(end.year,end.month,end.day,end.hour),inter))    
               
    return lst
    
# expand the duration
df['duration']=df.apply(genhourlist, axis=1)
df=df.explode('duration')

# update the duration and start
df['start']=df.duration.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['duration']=df.duration.apply(lambda x: x[1])

pd.pivot_table(df,index=['start'],columns=['activity'], values=['duration'],aggfunc='sum')
```

Result:

```
                                duration                
activity                 Eat   Sleep    Work
start                                       
2022-05-21 07:00:00      NaN  2162.0     NaN
2022-05-21 08:00:00      NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 09:00:00      NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 10:00:00      NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 11:00:00      NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 12:00:00     44.0  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 13:00:00   3600.0  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 14:00:00   3556.0  1428.0     NaN
2022-05-21 18:00:00      NaN     NaN   644.0
2022-05-21 19:00:00      NaN     NaN  7200.0
2022-05-21 20:00:00      NaN     NaN  7200.0
2022-05-21 21:00:00      NaN     NaN  2432.0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. However, I mean that for each hour there should be a sum of seconds for the activity that has elapsed during that hour. In this case, you received the sum of seconds of activities started at that time

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did with the 4 rows of data you posted.

Here's what I tried to do and my assumptions:

```
Goal = for each row, 
- calculate total elapsed time, 
- determine start hour sh, end hour eh, 
- work out how many seconds pertain to sh & eh

then:
-  create a 24-row df with results added up for all users (assuming the data starts at 00:00 and ends at 23:59 on the same day, there isn't any other day, and you're interested in the aggregate result for all users)
```

I'm using a For loop to build the final dataframe. It's probably not efficient enough if you have 10m rows in your original dataset, but it gets the job done on a smaller subset. Hopefully you can improve upon it!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# work out total elapsed time, in seconds
df['total'] = df['end_date'] - df['start_date']
df['total'] = df['total'].dt.total_seconds()

# determine start/end hours (just the value: 07:00 AM => 7)
df['sh'] = df['start_date'].dt.hour
df['eh'] = df['end_date'].dt.hour

#determine start/end hours again
df['next_hour'] = df['start_date'].dt.ceil('H') # 07:23:58 => 08:00:00
df['previous_hour'] = df['end_date'].dt.floor('H') # 14:23:48 => 14:00:00
df

# determine how many seconds pertain to start/end hours
df['sh_s'] = df['next_hour'] - df['start_date']
df['sh_s'] = df['sh_s'].dt.total_seconds()

df['eh_s'] = df['end_date'] - df['previous_hour']
df['eh_s'] = df['eh_s'].dt.total_seconds()

# where start hour & end hour are the same (start=07:20, end=07:30)
my_mask = df['sh'].eq(df['eh']).values
# set sh_s to be 07:30 - 07:20 = 10 minutes = 600 seconds
df['sh_s'] = df['sh_s'].where(~my_mask, other=(df['end_date'] - df['start_date']).dt.total_seconds())
# set eh_s to be 0
df['eh_s'] = df['eh_s'].where(~my_mask, other=0)
df


# add all column hours to df
hour_columns = np.arange(24)
df[hour_columns] = ''
df

# Sorry for this horrible loop below... Hopefully you can improve upon it or get rid of it completely!
for i in range(len(df)): # for each row:
    
    sh = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('sh')] # get start hour value
    sh_s = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('sh_s')] #get seconds pertaining to start hour
    
    eh = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('eh')] # get end hour value
    eh_s = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('eh_s')] #get seconds pertaining to end hour
    
    # fill in hour columns
    
    # if start hour = end hour:
    if sh == eh:
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc(sh)] = sh_s
        # but ignore eh_s (it would cancel out the previous line)
    # if start hour != end hour, report both to the hour columns:
    else:
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc(sh)] = sh_s
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc(eh)] = eh_s
    
    # for each col between sh & eh, input 3600
    for j in range(sh + 1, eh):
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc(j)] = 3600

df
df.groupby('activity', as_index=False)[hour_columns].sum().transpose()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your help. It works slowly, but except for one thing, the results are correct. However, when the start and end are at the same hour, it seems to me that the results are unfortunately wrong. For example, if start_date=end_date="2022-05-21 07:20:00", and activity="sleep" then I will still get the result 1200 for 7 o'clock.

Comment: Hello, good point! I've edited my answer and the case you brought up now yields 0. (however, why would you have an identical start date and end date?)

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer. Everything is now correct and it's working surprisingly fast. I expected it to be slower due to the loop. After the initial data aggregation it took about one minute for those 10 million rows. Identical start_date and end_date sometimes happens, but it doen't affect the result. This was just an example because in general the mistake would occur when start date and end_date were at the same hour.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#get difference in seconds between end and start
tot = df['end_date'].sub(df['start_date']).dt.total_seconds()

#repeat unique index values, if necessary create default
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(tot)].copy()
#add timedeltas in second to start datetimes
df['start'] = df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='s')
#create DatetimeIndex in hours with count activity - total seconds
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='H',key='start'), 'activity']).size().unstack()
print (df)
activity                Eat   Sleep    Work
start                                      
2022-05-21 07:00:00     NaN  2162.0     NaN
2022-05-21 08:00:00     NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 09:00:00     NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 10:00:00     NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 11:00:00     NaN  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 12:00:00    44.0  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 13:00:00  3600.0  3600.0     NaN
2022-05-21 14:00:00  3556.0  1428.0     NaN
2022-05-21 18:00:00     NaN     NaN   644.0
2022-05-21 19:00:00     NaN     NaN  7200.0
2022-05-21 20:00:00     NaN     NaN  7200.0
2022-05-21 21:00:00     NaN     NaN  2432.0
```